# HTTP/2 -- what's going on?

Tags: http, url, web, uri, http2

I plan to code a mighty web server. But I am unsure: should I do it in HTTP/1.x, or HTTP/2? I really don't like doing it in both (I know HTTP/2 is backward compatible to HTTP/1.x, but if it's superior AND is going to be adopted by the majority then I will only do it in HTTP/2 without the backward compatibility aspect).

How is the future looking like for HTTP/2? Are there any hints from standard bodies to change HTTP/2 or undo their mistakes?

Is HTTP/2 really worth it?

Finally, how is the expected HTTP/2 adoption by web browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How is the future looking like for HTTP/2?** and **Finally, how is the expected HTTP/2 adoption by web browsers?**

The HTTP/2 standard has passed acceptance and is being implemented by all major server vendors. In fact, server support has advanced, all major server vendors support HTTP/2 in their current releases. You can track all known implementations of [HTTP/2](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) here.

**Are there any hints from standard bodies to change HTTP/2 or undo their mistakes?**

There will not be an HTTP 2.x. The standards body has already made this clear (although I can't find a link that proves it). the next version will be HTTP/3.

**Is HTTP/2 really worth it?**
Yes. The benefits of [HTTP/2](https://readlearncode.com/http2-in-a-nutshell/) are too long to list here. This [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-http2-under-the-hood/index.html) discusses them in depth.

When developing a web server you will need to take account of both HTTP1.x and HTTP/2. At the moment we are transitioning to HTTP/2 but you should provide backward compatibility to HTTP/1.x.

Comment: TY. Any idea when will HTTP/3 be out?

Answer (score 2):

I would say this question is too broad for stack overflow, but will attempt and answer anyway:

> I plan to code a mighty web server. But I am unsure: should I do it in
>   HTTP/1.x, or HTTP/2? I really don't like doing it in both (I know
>   HTTP/2 is backward compatible to HTTP/1.x, but if it's superior AND is
>   going to be adopted by the majority then I will only do it in HTTP/2
>   without the backward compatibility aspect).

No offence, and will give you the benefit of the doubt here that you are not trolling, but writing a web server is a major undertaking and you'd need to have detailed knowledge of the HTTP protocol amongst other things and it appears you don't have that to be honest. So you'll need to do a few years reading on the subject first.

HTTP/2 is not backwards compatible to HTTP/1.1. You basically start in HTTP/1.1 and upgrade to HTTP/2 if you support it (at a simplistic level). So you need to support both. And will do for some time. Even though browser support is good (see below) there will be numerous devices that won't speak HTTP/2 for some time. Some devices (primarily bots admittedly) still only speak HTTP/1.0.

> How is the future looking like for HTTP/2? Are there any hints from standard bodies to change HTTP/2 or undo their mistakes?

Way too broad for Stackoverflows format.

> Is HTTP/2 really worth it?

Yes.

> Finally, how is the expected HTTP/2 adoption by web browsers?

HTTP/2 adoption can be seen here: http://caniuse.com/#search=http2